# OpenCV app compiled with C++11 creates extra thread

Tags: multithreading, opencv, c++11, gdb

I'm debugging a OpenCV app compiled with C++11 (I use OpenCV 2.4.10). The app has two threads that do some image processing on the CPU (no GPU functions used but I also included `libopencv_gpu.so` in the linked libraries).

Using gdb I noticed that instead of just two threads (the main process thread and another thread created by the main process thread) I found 3 threads running:

```
(gdb) info threads 
Id   Target Id         Frame 
78   Thread 0x7fffe2ff5700 (LWP 20531) "app_name" 0x00007ffff5bb2f3d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
2    Thread 0x7fffe3c42700 (LWP 20454) "app_name" 0x00007ffff5bdf12d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
* 1    Thread 0x7ffff7fab800 (LWP 20450) "app_name" 0x00007ffff5bb2f3d in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
```

Thread 1 and 78 (using gdb ID) are executing my code. I added a sleep call in each one so I can make sure that those are my threads.
Thread 2 (using gdb ID) is created before entering the main function of the main process I believe. As far as I could debug this, thread with ID 2 just calls poll() function all the time.

I'm new to gdb and maybe you can tell me how to find out who creates this thread and what is it's purpose? Is this OpenCV related or C++11? When I compile the same app using Opencv4Tegra and run it on a Tegra K1 board, thread number 2 does not exist.

**EDIT**
This is the backtrace when creating thread number 2. It seems that libusb creates this but I don't know why yet:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __pthread_create_2_1 (newthread=0x7fffea79c438, attr=0x0, start_routine=0x7fffea5941c0, arg=0x0) at pthread_create.c:466
#1  0x00007fffea5943df in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fffea5926a5 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fffea58b715 in libusb_init () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff2f06a0e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.22
#5  0x00007ffff2ef5465 in dc1394_new () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.22
#6  0x00007ffff6f615e9 in CvDC1394::CvDC1394() () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
#7  0x00007ffff6f373f0 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_cap_dc1394_v2.cpp () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
#8  0x00007ffff7dea13a in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=3, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffdcd8, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffdcf8) at dl-init.c:78
#9  0x00007ffff7dea223 in call_init (env=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:36
#10 _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe1c8, argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdcd8, env=0x7fffffffdcf8) at dl-init.c:126
#11 0x00007ffff7ddb30a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

(gdb) quit
```

Comment: Can you examine the call stack of thread 2?  That might yield more information, such as the top-level thread function.

Comment: `highgui -> libdc1394` that's Firewire cameras. Are you capturing images from a cam (`cv::VideoCapture`)?

Comment: And then bizarrely, calls to libusb - seems libdc1394 can support some USB cameras as well.  At a rough guess, you're running this on a laptop with a built-in camera, hence the thread getting created, and your Tegra board doesn't have one attached.

Comment: I guess you guys are correct ... just found calls to highgui in the code. Thanks